# Fibre product and submersion of PL-manifolds

Tags: ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Let us consider the fibre product $M\times_{f,g} M'$ of $M \xrightarrow{f} N \xleftarrow{g} M'$.
If $M,M'$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $f$ is a submersion, then $M\times_{f,g} M'$ is again a smooth manifold in a natural way, if I am not mistaken.

What can analogously be said about PL-manifolds? I.e. I have two questions:

1. What is the correct definition of a submersion for PL-manifolds?
2. Is it then true that if in the diagram above $M,M',N$ are PL-manifolds, the maps $f,g$ are PL and $f$ is such a PL-submersion that the fibre product $M\times_{f,g} M'$ is again a PL-manifold?

I guess, in the smooth category the crucial thing is transversality and there should be a notion of transversality for submanifolds in the PL-category. I would be very happy about some references. I couldn't find such a result in the standard text books like Zeeman, Rourke-Sanderson, Stallings or Hudson (at least at first glance). But I just started to study PL topology and maybe this is just a (simple) exercise.